# How to upload image through web service in node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-services, image-uploading

I have a web-service `http:example.com/updateimage` with the below parameters:

1. token (user token)
2. digest
3. imageData (Base64-encoded)

I don't know how can I upload image on the another service? And what `imageData parameter`contains?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module along the lines:

```
var formData = {
  token: user_token,
  digest: your_digest,
  imageData: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/your_image.jpg'),
};

request.post({url:'http://example.com/updateimage', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```